# Delay in execution of dispatch_async block with AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate methods

Tags: ios, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently working on a project involving `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` for blink detection.

I have the following `dispatch_async` block in the delegate method

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

//Initialisation of buffer and UIImage and CIDetector, etc.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        if(features.count > 0){
            CIFaceFeature *feature = [features objectAtIndex:0];
            if([feature leftEyeClosed]&&[feature rightEyeClosed]){
                flag = TRUE;
            }else{
                if(flag){
                    blinkcount++;
                    //Update UILabel containing blink count. The count variable is incremented from here.
                }
            flag = FALSE;
            }
    }
}
```

The method shown above gets called continuously and processes the video feed from the camera. The `flag` boolean keeps track whether the eye was closed or open in the last frame so that blink may be detected. There are a substantial number of frames getting dropped, but still the blink is properly detected, so I guess the fps processed are adequate.

My problem is that the `UILabel` gets updated after a substantial delay (~1 sec) after the blink has been performed. This makes the app look laggy and unintuitive. I tried writing the UI updation code without the dispatch, but that is a no go. Is there something I could do so that the `UILabel` gets instantaneously updated after the blink is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know exactly what's going on here without more of the code, but above the dispatch code, you say:

```
//Initialisation of buffer and UIImage and CIDetector, etc.
```

If you're really initializing the detector every time, that's probably suboptimal -- make it long-lived. I don't know for *sure* that initializing a CIDetector is expensive, but it's a place to start. Also if you're really using UIImage here, that's also suboptimal. Don't go via UIImage, take the more direct route:

```
CVImageBufferRef ib = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer: ib];
NSArray* features = [longLivedDetector featuresInImage: ciImage];
```

Lastly, do the feature detection on the background thread, and only marshal the UILabel update back to the main thread. Like this:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    if (!_longLivedDetector) {
        _longLivedDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context: ciContext options: whatever];
    }

    CVImageBufferRef ib = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer: ib];
    NSArray* features = [_longLivedDetector featuresInImage: ciImage];
    if (!features.count)
        return;

    CIFaceFeature *feature = [features objectAtIndex:0];
    const BOOL leftAndRightClosed = [feature leftEyeClosed] && [feature rightEyeClosed];

    // Only trivial work is left to do on the main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if (leftAndRightClosed) {
            flag = TRUE;
        } else {
            if (flag) {
                blinkcount++;
                //Update UILabel containing blink count. The count variable is incremented from here.
            }
            flag = FALSE;
        }
    });
}
```

In closing, you should also remember that facial feature detection is a non-trivial signal processing task, it takes significant computation (i.e. time) to complete. I would expect there will come a point when there's just no way to make it any faster without the hardware being faster.